# "more people becoming increasingly xxx" or "more people increasingly becoming xxx"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, adverbs, word-order

I need a bit of guidance regarding the following sentence. Which of the three variants is grammatical?

> - Are more people becoming increasingly intolerant?
> - Are more people increasingly becoming intolerant?
> - Are people increasingly becoming more intolerant?

Comment: @BraddSzonye I would have certainly used a more toned down example but it's just that a certain horrendous incident happened yesterday with a 5 year old child and this particular sentence came up in my mind. I am sorry but I couldn't help

Comment: Yeah, I now see 2 downvotes :D But never mind, like you said, I have now changed the questions accordingly.

Comment: @BraddSzonye All thanks to you, the concept is now absolutely clear. Thank you once again :))

Comment: No need to thank me – that's what accepting and upvotes are for. Comments are for constructive criticism, not chat. I'll delete most of my comments here as they're no longer relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the two examples, *increasingly* modifies different words:

- Are more people becoming **increasingly intolerant**?
- Are more people **increasingly becoming** intolerant?

The first example suggests both an increase in number and degree: more people *and* increasing intolerance. The second example suggests only an increase in number, but does so redundantly: more people *and* increasing occurrence. If you intend the latter meaning, a better wording would be, “Are more people becoming intolerant?”

Comment: Thank you so much @Bradd Szonye. Your guidance is very much appreciated :)) Thank you once again.